# not able to install R in centos 7

Tags: r, installation

I have tried all the available resources, and felt so bad about this R installation in Centos 7. It throws up following Error.

```
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tcl-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicu-devel
Error: Package: R-java-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: pcre-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: zlib-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: redhat-rpm-config
Error: Package: R-java-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-headless
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libX11-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tk-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libquadmath.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: gcc-c++
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(dvips)
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: openblas-Rblas-0.2.19-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: openblas-Rblas-0.2.19-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xz-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtk8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: bzip2-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: cups
Error: Package: R-core-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: gcc-gfortran
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please help me in solving this error.

Regards,
Ateeq

Comment: Have you tried `yum install R`?

Comment: Yes tried doing that, but lot of sub dependencies. and throw the error as above

Comment: I am totally sad with this, been trying to install R from last 2 days but failed. feeling miserable.

Comment: just install all the packages he is complaining about...